# Auth.net SDK how to update TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2

Tags: sdk, authorize.net

I'm currently using this https://github.com/objco/anet_php_sdk/tree/master/lib library for my current SDK and I wanted to update to the latest. As you can see this github mirror 6 years old. Can I just copy and paste the "lib" from auth.net's github https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/tree/master/lib into my "lib" to update the latest TLS1.2 ? Thanks

Comment: You don't upgrade your code to support TLS 1.2. You update your server.

Comment: is openssl 1.0.1e-fips supports tls 1.2 ?